# I am getting FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'user.txt'. How can I call it differently?

Tags: python, ios

```
users = open('user.txt','r')
userInfo = users.readlines()

accessOne = False
accessTwo = False

while accessOne == False:
    username = input('Username: ')

    for line in userInfo:

        if line.split(' ')[0].strip(',') == username:
            accessOne = True

            while accessTwo == False:
                password = input('Password: ')

                if line.split(' ')[1].strip('\n') == password:
                    accessTwo = True
                    break

                else:
                    accessTwo = False
                    print('Incorrect password, please try again.')
                    continue
        else:
            accessOne = False
            continue
        break
```

Comment: Try using the full path for `'user.txt'`, otherwise the script will only look in the current directory

Comment: If this ('/Users/shauntemmers/Dropbox/47418/Introduction to Programming/Task 25/user.txt') is my full path how do I implement it? I tried a view ways but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

try using the full path for the file and the with open method Also,
you can try this alternative in the line 1 instead of yours,

```
with open('Your_file_name', 'method') as USER
```

actually there might a case that you did not close the users file, try using the users.close() in the end, if you wish to follow with your code, else you can try the above method

Comment: I changed the first line to your's but it's still giving the same result. Also, I do have users.close()

Comment: Did you check the file path Like try having the full path to the file

Answer (score 0):

Depends:

1. Use Try Except block to check file than and there.
2. Find absolute file path by using os module functionalities.
3. There are number of ways to open a file. It depends on your logic if your file is not accessible or permission issue.